# Angular 6 Bootstrap Affix

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular6, scrollspy, bootstrap-affix

I'm trying to do affix or scrollspy functionality of Bootstrap 4 on Angular 6. However, I trying to find existing libraries. I found this one [JonnyBGod's scrollspy](https://github.com/JonnyBGod/ngx-scrollspy) but unfortunately, it is still on Angular 5 and also using the rxjs 5. Are there any existing libraries out there that are already using RxJS 6. can you guys recommend?

BTW, I am trying to at least make JonnyBGod's library work with angular 6 by using the rxjs's migration guide. But if anyone knows any library out there that is natively written using angular 6 it is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can use thisissoon's  [angular-scrollspy](https://github.com/thisissoon/angular-scrollspy). I have used it in my angular 6 project, it's working perfectly fine.

**Below are the steps to set it up**

**Step 1: Install**

```
npm i @thisissoon/{angular-scrollspy,angular-inviewport} --save
```

**Step 2: Import in app.module.ts**

```
import { InViewportModule, WindowRef } from '@thisissoon/angular-inviewport';
import { ScrollSpyModule } from '@thisissoon/angular-scrollspy';

// Provide window object for browser and a suitable replacement
// on other platforms
const getWindow = () => window;
const providers: Provider[] = [{ provide: WindowRef, useFactory: getWindow }];

@NgModule({
  imports: [InViewportModule.forRoot(providers), ScrollSpyModule.forRoot()]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**Step 3: Add it in your component (example navbar.component.ts)**

```
<ul role="navigation" snScrollSpy id="foo">
  <li><a snScrollSpyItem for="foo" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a snScrollSpyItem for="foo" href="#about">About Us</a></li>
  <li><a snScrollSpyItem for="foo" href="#team">Team</a></li>
  <li><a snScrollSpyItem for="foo" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

 <sn-scroll-spy-section id="home" for="foo">
      Home Content
 </sn-scroll-spy-section>
 <sn-scroll-spy-section id="about" for="foo">
      About Us Content
 </sn-scroll-spy-section>
 <sn-scroll-spy-section id="team" for="foo">
      Team Content
 </sn-scroll-spy-section>
 <sn-scroll-spy-section id="contact" for="foo">
    Contact Us content
 </sn-scroll-spy-section>
```

**PS:** This is also working if each section is inside a separate(nested) components.